# Package manager failure

Tags: package-management

After following [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264110) to the end, which was not technically solved (the user just purchased a new computer), I am left hanging.

I believe that my package manager is either half installed, not installed, or just broken.
I think the route to take is to somehow install it from a LiveUSB (Ubuntu 14.04.5). I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

*Note: all apt-get install/purge/remove/etc. commands return a similar error and therefore I can not install the linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic package.*

Here is the output of some of the requested commands from that thread:

```
mcordaro@HAL9000L:/$ sudo apt-get install -f -y
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 280 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 456 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 472475 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic (3.13.0-100.147) ...
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-100-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
dkms: WARNING: Linux headers are missing, which may explain the above failures.
      please install the linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic package to fix this.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-100-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-100-generic: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.13.0-100-generic
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-100-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: 0r§mûü…ooEhttps://console.aws.amazon.com/p/log/1/lambda/1/OP/: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: ØA
—Eoúô: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: ˆ¹ù+œ.£^»ù+œ.HTTP/1.1: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: 0r§mûü…ooEhttps://console.aws.amazon.com/p/log/1/lambda/1/OP/: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: /usr/share/initramfs-
ools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: ˆ¹ù+œ.£^»ù+œ.HTTP/1.1: not found
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g failed with return 127.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-100-generic with 127.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic (3.13.0-112.159) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-112-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-112-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-112-generic: No such file or directory
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: 0r§mûü…ooEhttps://console.aws.amazon.com/p/log/1/lambda/1/OP/: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: ØA
—Eoúô: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: ˆ¹ù+œ.£^»ù+œ.HTTP/1.1: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: 0r§mûü…ooEhttps://console.aws.amazon.com/p/log/1/lambda/1/OP/: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: ØA
—Eoúô: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: ˆ¹ù+œ.£^»ù+œ.HTTP/1.1: not found
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g failed with return 127.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-112-generic with 127.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic (3.13.0-95.142) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-95-generic
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: 0r§mûü…ooEhttps://console.aws.amazon.com/p/log/1/lambda/1/OP/: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: ˆ¹ù+œ.£^»ù+œ.HTTP/1.1: not found
ØA
—Eoúô: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: 0r§mûü…ooEhttps://console.aws.amazon.com/p/log/1/lambda/1/OP/: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: ØA
—Eoúô: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: ˆ¹ù+œ.£^»ù+œ.HTTP/1.1: not found
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g failed with return 127.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-95-generic with 127.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
mcordaro@HAL9000L:/$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image-extra*
rH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic        3.13.0-100.147                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic        3.13.0-112.159                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic         3.13.0-95.142                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
mcordaro@HAL9000L:/$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image-3.13.0-*
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic              3.13.0-100.147                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic              3.13.0-112.159                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic               3.13.0-24.47                            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic               3.13.0-27.50                            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-29-generic               3.13.0-29.53                            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic               3.13.0-39.66                            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic               3.13.0-43.72                            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic               3.13.0-45.74                            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic               3.13.0-52.86                            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic               3.13.0-54.91                            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic               3.13.0-57.95                            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic               3.13.0-61.100                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic               3.13.0-62.102                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic               3.13.0-63.103                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic               3.13.0-65.106                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic               3.13.0-66.108                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic               3.13.0-76.120                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-85-generic               3.13.0-85.129                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic               3.13.0-95.142                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Please note that I tried posting this at https://ubuntuforums.org but I keep recieving an Apache 403 error when submitting.

Comment: `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g: 1: /etc/default/ntfs-3g: 0r§mûü…ooEhttps://console.aws.amazon.com/p/log/1/lambda/1/OP/: not found`

It looks like your /etc/default/ntfs-3g file got filled with garbage. Any idea how that could have happened?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your package manager.

Problems like this usually occur when the human requests an impossible situation, and the system is valiantly tries to obey.

Read the error message carefully, line by line. The error messages will usually tell you what the problem is.

Here's the first problem to fix. Note that the error message tells you exactly how to fix it.

```
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-100-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
dkms: WARNING: Linux headers are missing, which may explain the above failures.
  please install the linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic package to fix this.
```

*No such file or directory* errors occur when a user manually deletes files placed by the package manager. That's an unwise thing to do - it breaks your system, as you have discovered.

Since you seem to wish to remove the package, you can either create a dummy file or directory for the package manger to remove, or your can --reinstall the package first.

Comment: Sorry. I should have stated that all `apt-get` commands return this error. So I can not install the package requested.

Comment: Then today is the day you learn how to use dpkg. Afterward, you will have a better understanding of why we use apt. Or use dummy files.